# Read large blobs from json stream

Tags: c#, json, asynchronous, stream, json.net

I need to work with a JSON stream that contains large blobs of data (but not that many nodes), for example:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "status": "ok"
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "name of item 1",
      "data": "In reality this could be a really long string of several hundred MB."
    }
  ]
}
```

When reading this JSON stream I want to process the `data` string as the data is coming in without the need to have the entire string in memory.

Json.NET has a `JsonReader` class which allows to decode the nodes as they are coming in, but it keeps the *entire* nodes in memory.

Is there a way to achieve what I want with Json.NET or is there another JSON library out there which can do that (must be .Net Core compatible)?

Note: For XML this can be solved using the `System.Xml.XmlReader` class which as a `ReadValueChunkAsync` method that allows to read large data in chunks from the incoming stream.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems sounds like something that would not be part of the library as it is very particular. The size problems with JSON usually come from processing huge arrays, for which a solution in Newtonsoft.JSON exists (i.e. pass a StreamReader to a JsonReader).

Does this maybe help you?

http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/parsing-big-records-with-jsonnet/240165316

Comment: I've come across that drdobbs article. It explains how to read nodes from a stream, but not how to read a value in chunks.

Comment: is fixing it on the sender side an option? Having strings in a JSON object that cause out of memory exceptions seems like a huge red flag. Whatever solution you find on the receivers side, fixing it on the senders side would be the least "hacky" way to do it.

Comment: I agree that JSON is a pretty bad format to transmit this kind of data. But unfortunately I'm not owning the sender side.